# How to send request through an SSH host

Tags: curl, ssh, postman

### Intro

I am in a machine **A**, there is an *middle machine([Jump Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jump_server))* named **B**, and a 'outside' machine **C**. Since I can not connect **C** directly, but I can ssh login to **B**.

For now i will firstly `ssh` login to **B**, then send a request from **B**, eg:

```
$ ssh myname@<ip_B> -p <port_B>
myname@<ip_B>'s password:
Last login: Tue Aug  7 10:14:21 2018 from ...
```

After I login to **B** I sent post using `curl`.

```
[myname@<ip_B>]$ curl -X POST http://<ip_C>:<port_C>/<route> -F 'my_post_key=my_post_value'
```

### Question

- I wonder if I can use **B** as an SSH host and send my request From **A** directly using `curl`?
- Since I am using [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com), is there any solution in Postman ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could use a tunnel, something like this:

```
$ ssh -N -L 8080:machine-C:80 machine-B
```

The option `-L` will do a local port forwarding from port 8080 (**machine-A**) to port 80 in **machine-C** going through **machine-B**.

Then from **machine-A**:

```
$ curl -H "host: example.com" 0:8080
```

You may need to pass the `host` header in case the **machine-C** is hosting multiple sites.

Once the tunnel is up, in postman you could use `127.0.0.1:8080`

Comment: The first ssh command also is being run on the **machine-A**.

Answer (score 0):

Using postman, this can easily be done via following steps

1. Add a custom proxy configuration in postman settings, make sure the SSH tunnelling is already done via AWS CLI `aws ssm start-session` command or via  `ssh -N` command

[image]

2. Hit the Http request with host and endpoint needed

[image]

Done. Thanks!